# How to specify the same Type of class for a returned value in an interface method?

Tags: java, interface

I'm creating a new interface in Java, and I want to create a method that returns de same type of the class that implements the interface.

Example:

```
public interface ModelInterface {
    public (TypeOfClass) getAll();
}

public class Object1 implements ModelInterface {
    public Object1 getAll(){

    }
}

public class Object2 implements ModelInterface {
    public Object2 getAll(){

    }
}
```

How I can accomplish this?

Comment: simplest way would be to use `Object` and typecast the result depending on the class that implements the interface...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has the feature of covariant return types.  This means that subclasses can specify a subclass of the method's return type when overriding/implementing the method.  It's as simple as

```
public interface ModelInterface {
    public ModelInterface getAll();
}

public class Object1 implements ModelInterface {
    public Object1 getAll(){
        // implement here
    }
}

public class Object2 implements ModelInterface {
    public Object2 getAll(){
        // implement here
    }
}
```

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) provides an explanation for covariant return types.

> Suppose that you have a class hierarchy in which ImaginaryNumber is a subclass of java.lang.Number, which is in turn a subclass of Object.
>
> Now suppose that you have a method declared to return a Number:
>
> ```
> public Number returnANumber() {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> The returnANumber method can return an ImaginaryNumber but not an Object. ImaginaryNumber is a Number because it's a subclass of Number. However, an Object is not necessarily a Number — it could be a String or another type.
>
> You can override a method and define it to return a subclass of the original method, like this:
>
> ```
> public ImaginaryNumber returnANumber() {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> This technique, called covariant return type, means that the return type is allowed to vary in the same direction as the subclass.
>
> Note: You also can use interface names as return types. In this case, the object returned must implement the specified interface.

Comment: But any code using the interface (good code!) would still see `ModelInterface getAll()`, not the refined type. So, except for a slight refinement *in* the method (as the returned object would be upcast silently anyway) it's not a particularly useful feature in context.

Comment: True.  The question you've raised is whether the OP requires a reference to the interface to be able to return a reference to an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate such a return type in an interface by using generics

```
interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
  T method();
}
```

This way you are reminded by the compiler that the generic type must be compatible to a type that implements `Foo` This type might be `Foo` itself or any other type that implements this interface. When using:

```
class Bar implements Foo<Bar>
```

all of your methods are however forced to return `Foo` as expected.